# Problem working with face-api.js and Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop, face-api

I'm building a photoshop plugin able to detect faces landmarks using face-api.js. It seems to work fine only with browsers but having some problems within photoshop. it stops working when it reaches the line `await faceapi.detectSingleFace(image).withFaceLandmarks()`  but returns no errors.

This is my function to take the 68 points:

```
   var all_points = [];

   async function promise(){
      await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('http://localhost:3000/models'),
      await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('http://localhost:3000/models'),
      await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri('http://localhost:3000/models')
   }

   promise();

   async function takePoints(){
      alert('takepoints!')                             #this works
      var img = await fetch(path_img)
      var myBlob = await img.blob()
      var image = await faceapi.bufferToImage(myBlob)

      alert(image.src)                                 #this works

      var displaySize = { width: image.width, height: image.height }
      var detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(image).withFaceLandmarks()

      alert(detections.landmarks)                      #not working

      var resizedDetections = await faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
      var all_points = resizedDetections.landmarks._positions
      alert(all_points)

      return all_points
   }  

document.getElementById("my-btn").addEventListener('click', takePoints)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add the following to your script after
`var detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(image).withFaceLandmarks()`

`var landmarks = await faceapi.detectFaceLandmarks(image)`

And I think I had a problem using
`await faceapi.detectSingleFace(image).withFaceLandmarks()`

Try this instead `await faceapi.detectAllFaces(image).withFaceLandmarks()`